# useEffect with empty array dependency is called twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Here is useEffect hook of my page components:

```
const QuizPage = () => {
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hey");
  }, []);
```

and hey is showing twice.

Here is the part where the QuizPage component is rendered.

```
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/quiz" element={<Quiz />} /> // <- this is quiz component
        <Route path="/result" element={<Result />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
```

is react router dom route rendered twice?
thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What's your React version?

Comment: Are you using `<StrictMode>` and react 18? If so, this is expected in development builds. https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state